# Other than .profile, where do shell environment variables get defined?

Tags: solaris, bourne-shell

Using Bourne shell on Solaris 10, there are many environment variables defined that are not in the .profile. Where and how do these get defined?

Answer (score 1):

Try looking in /etc/profile and /etc/default/login on Solaris.  Some values may be built-in defaults or picked up from the environment, such as LOGNAME or HOSTNAME.

Comment: So by built-in do you mean they are not defined anywhere in a script file but are created by the shell itself when it starts up? Are these documented anywhere? Thanx.

Comment: I'm not sure where to find it fully documented, but it is pretty clear there are many variables shown by a command like "set" which are not derived from the files in /etc.  Most if not all of the variables can be updated with your own value (e.g. PS1).  Here is one site talking about it.  http://mtxia.com/css/Training/Shell Programming/sh2a.html

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `~/.profile`, they are defined (first) in `/etc/profile`.

See the [sh (1) man page](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/816-5165/sh-1.html).

Which particular variables are you asking about?

Answer (score 0):

Env vars can be set in a lot of places: startup scripts, /etc/profile for users without a .profile, via cron, via service startups...anything that is read, referenced, or executed.